# Inhereting a virtual class interface from a DLL (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, dll

I have a DLL which exports a virtual interface to a class. I want to inherit that interface but keep the functionality from the DLL.

DLL.h (header which I use to include DLL)

```
#ifndef EXPORT
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXPORT IClassA {
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

EXPORT IClassA* new_IClassA(int a, int b);
```

Internal.h

```
#include "DLL.h"

class ClassA : public IClassA {
public:
    ClassA(int a, int b);
    int foo();
    int bar();
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

DLL.cpp

```
#include "internal.h"


ClassA::ClassA(int a, int b) { this->b = b; this->a = a; }
int ClassA::foo() { return a; }
int ClassA::bar() { return b; }


IClassA* new_IClassA(int a, int b) {
    return new ClassA(a, b);
}
```

How can I inherit IClassA (In a project that includes the DLL ) without redefining the foo() and bar() (since in my project that would not be possible) and using the ones defined in ClassA insead?

e.g.

```
class ClassB : public IClassA {
public:
    // I have no idea how to make a suitable constructor
    int baz() { return c };
private:
    int c;
}
```

So that now ClassB has the methods foo(), bar() and, baz().

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are pure virtual member functions. `ClassB` _must_ define those functions. if they don't you cannot instantiate them. If you want to inherit the functionality from `ClassA` you need to derive from _that_ class instead of `IClassA`.

Comment: ClassB needs to call new_IClassA() in its constructor and implement foo and bar which simply call IClassA->foo and bar.  A kind of composition called aggregation, it is very mechanical but you don't get help from the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How can I inherit IClassA without redefining the foo() and bar() and using the ones defined in ClassA instead?`

Answer is: **you can't**.

Any implementation of `IClassA` must implement `foo()` and `bar()`.

If you want `ClassB` to reuse the implementation of `ClassA::foo()` and `ClassA::bar()`, then, you must have `ClassA` be exported from your dll (as `IClassA` is) and have `ClassB` derive from `ClassA` (rather than `IClassA`).

```
class EXPORT ClassA : public IClassA {
    ...
};
```

Then, you may consider removing `EXPORT IClassA* new_IClassA(int a, int b);` as people using your dll can directly create `ClassA` objects.

EDIT:

As commented by *Hans Passant* (and I thought about it overnight and was about to add this edit when I saw the commanet ;-):  If `ClassA`'s `foo()` and `bar()` code are complex and if you really want to reuse them, then, have `ClassB` maintain a `ClassA` attribute. `ClassB` must implement `foo()` and `bar()` but does not need to duplicate `ClassA`'s code:

```
class ClassB : public IClassA {
public:
    ClassB( int _a, int _b, int _c ) : pA( new_IClassA( _a, _b ) ), c( _c ) {}
    ~ClassB() { delete pA; }

    int foo() { return pA->foo(); }
    int bar() { return pA->bar(); }
    int baz() { return c };

private:
    ClassA* pA;
    int c;
};
```